# can't bind 'root' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-buttons'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

afternoon Everyone, am trying to compile my app and am getting this error;
'can't bind 'root' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-buttons''. i have tried various changes and still nothing.

> my home.html

```
    <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar color="primary">
              <ion-title start>Ibada</ion-title>
                <ion-buttons end detail-push navPush="DetailPage">
                  <button ion-button icon-only color="royal">
                    <ion-icon name="chatbubbles">
                      <ion-badge item-end>5</ion-badge>
                    </ion-icon>
                  </button>
                </ion-buttons>
                <ion-buttons end detail-push navPush="DefaultPage" [root]="{default: default}">
                  <button ion-button icon-only color="royal">
                    <ion-icon name="person-add"></ion-icon>
                  </button>
                </ion-buttons>
            </ion-toolbar>
          </ion-header>


          <ion-content class="mybackground">
            <div>
              <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                <img src="../../assets/imgs/sliders/word.jpg">
              </ion-thumbnail>
            </div>

          <ion-card>
              <ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let profile of (profileData | async)?.slice().reverse()">
                <p class="headertext"> Dear<strong> {{profile.firstname}} {{profile.lastname}}</strong><br/>
                  Welcome to</p>
                  <h1 class="headertext"> The Good News Mission </h1>
                  <p class="mytextcenter">A Missionary Sending church</p>
                  <hr/>
                  <p class="textleft">I am so happy to see you again <strong>{{profile.firstname}}</strong>. I can assure you that you will be blessed a lot as you explore our Ibada App. <br/><br/>
                    <strong>~ Pastor Moses Mwicigi~</strong> </p>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-card>


            <ion-card>
              <ion-item color="partial" text-center >
                <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft" item-left></ion-icon> Verse of the Day <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
                  </ion-item>
                    <ion-slides>
                      <ion-slide *ngFor="let verse of (verseDataList  | async)?.slice().reverse()"
                        detail-push navPush="VerseOfTheDayPage" [root]="{verse:verse}">
                        <ion-grid>
                          <ion-row color="partial">
                            <ion-col col-1><ion-icon name="sunny" item-left></ion-icon></ion-col>
                            <ion-col col-5><p class="paragraph"> Verse of the day</p> </ion-col>
                            <ion-col col-6> <p><strong>{{verse.date1}}</strong></p> </ion-col>
                          </ion-row>
                        </ion-grid>
                        <h2> {{verse.bibleverse}} </h2>
                        <p class="textleft"> {{verse.content}}</p>
                      </ion-slide>
                    </ion-slides>
                </ion-card>

                <ion-card>
                  <ion-item color="partial" text-center >
                    <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft" item-left></ion-icon> Read Our Sermon <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-slides>
                    <ion-slide *ngFor="let sermon of (sermonData | async)?.slice().reverse()"
                    detail-push navPush="SermonPage" [root]="{sermon:sermon}">
                    <ion-row>
                      <ion-col class="textleft">
                        <div>
                          <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                            <img style="width: 100%; "  src="../../assets/imgs/dating.jpg"></ion-thumbnail>
                          </div>
                          <h2 style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px"><strong>{{sermon.heading}}</strong><br/> <ion-icon style="float:right" name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon><ion-note item-right>
                          {{sermon.date1}} {{sermon.time}}
                          </ion-note></h2>
                          <p>{{sermon.content | slice:0:160}}...<span color="secondary">Read More</span></p>
                        </ion-col>
                      </ion-row>
                      <ion-row>
                        <ion-col>
                          <button ion-button icon-left clear small color="danger">
                            <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
                            <div>12 Like</div>
                          </button>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col>
                          <button ion-button clear small color="danger" icon-start>
                            <ion-icon name='heart'></ion-icon>
                            Love
                          </button>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col>
                          <button ion-button icon-left clear small color="danger">
                            <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
                            <div>4 Comments</div>
                          </button>
                        </ion-col>
                      </ion-row>
                    </ion-slide>
                  </ion-slides>
                </ion-card>

<!--Connect with friends-->
                <ion-card >
                  <ion-item color="partial" text-center>
                    Become a friend....
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-slides>
                    <ion-slide>
                      <ion-item>
                        <ion-grid>
                          <h4>Pastor Moses Mwicigi</h4>
                          <ion-row>
                            <ion-col col-5>
                              <div>
                                <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                  <img style="width: 100%;border-radius:20px"  src="../../assets/imgs/mwicigi.jpg"></ion-thumbnail>
                                </div>
                                <p>1 Mutual Friend</p>
                                <button ion-button color="secondary" clear>Add</button>
                            </ion-col>

                            <ion-col col-7 class="textleft">
                              <p><strong>Nationality:</strong> Kenyan</p>
                              <p><strong>Marital status:</strong> Married to Jackline Mwicigi</p>
                              <p class="paragraph"> I am a pastor at The Good News Mission, A husband and an investor.</p>
                              <button ion-button color="secondary" clear end>Remove</button>
                            </ion-col>
                          </ion-row>
                        </ion-grid>
                      </ion-item>
                    </ion-slide>

                    <ion-slide>
                      <ion-item>
                        <ion-grid>
                          <h4><strong>Jackline Njeri</strong></h4>
                          <ion-row>
                            <ion-col col-5>
                              <div>
                                <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                  <img style="width: 100%; border-radius:20px"  src="../../assets/imgs/love1.jpg"></ion-thumbnail>
                                </div>
                                <p>1 Mutual Friend</p>
                                <button ion-button color="secondary" clear>Add</button>
                            </ion-col>

                            <ion-col col-7 class="textleft">
                              <p><strong>Nationality:</strong> Kenyan</p>
                              <p><strong>Marital status:</strong> Married</p>
                              <p class="paragraph">I am married to is the wife to the senior Pastor at The Good News ministry International. </p>
                              <button ion-button color="secondary" clear end>Remove</button>
                            </ion-col>
                          </ion-row>
                        </ion-grid>
                      </ion-item>
                    </ion-slide>
                  </ion-slides>
                </ion-card>

          <!--End Connect with friends-->


                <ion-item color="partial" text-center>
                  News & Events
                </ion-item>
                <ion-card>
                  <ion-slides>
                    <ion-slide *ngFor="let announcements of (announcementsDataList | async)?.slice().reverse()" detail-push navPush="AnnouncementsPage" [root]="{announcements:announcements}">
                      <ion-item text-center>
                        <h2>{{announcements.heading}}</h2>
                      </ion-item>
                      <hr/>
                      <div>
                        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                          <img style="width: 100%"  src="../../assets/imgs/tgnm.png"></ion-thumbnail>
                        </div>
                        <ion-card-content class="mytextleft">
                          <p>{{announcements.content | slice:0:119 }}</p>
                        </ion-card-content>
                        <ion-row>
                          <ion-col>
                            <button ion-button icon-left clear small color="danger">
                              <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
                              <div>12 Like</div>
                            </button>
                          </ion-col>
                          <ion-col>
                            <button ion-button clear small color="danger" icon-start>
                              <ion-icon name='heart'></ion-icon>
                              Love
                            </button>
                          </ion-col>
                          <ion-col>
                            <button ion-button icon-left clear small color="danger">
                              <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
                              <div>4 Comments</div>
                            </button>
                          </ion-col>
                        </ion-row>
                      </ion-slide>
                    </ion-slides>
                  </ion-card>


                  <ion-card>
                    <ion-item color="partial" text-center >
                     <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft" item-left></ion-icon> Read Our Blogs <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-slides>
                      <ion-slide *ngFor="let blog of (blogDataList | async)?.slice().reverse()" detail-push navPush="BlogPage" [root]="{blog:blog}">
                        <ion-row>
                          <ion-col class="textleft">
                            <div>
                              <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                <img style="width: 100%"  src="../../assets/imgs/dating2.jpg"></ion-thumbnail>
                              </div>
                              <h2 style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px"><strong>{{blog.heading}}</strong><br/> <ion-icon style="float:right" name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon><ion-note item-right>
                              {{blog.date1}} {{blog.time}}
                              </ion-note></h2>
                              <p>{{blog.content | slice:0:160}}...<span color="secondary">Read More</span></p>
                            </ion-col>
                          </ion-row>
                          <ion-row>
                            <ion-col>
                              <button ion-button icon-left clear small color="danger">
                                <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
                                <div>12 Like</div>
                              </button>
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col>
                              <button ion-button clear small color="danger" icon-start>
                                <ion-icon name='heart'></ion-icon>
                                Love
                              </button>
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col>
                              <button ion-button icon-left clear small color="danger">
                                <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
                                <div>4 Comments</div>
                              </button>
                            </ion-col>
                          </ion-row>
                        </ion-slide>
                      </ion-slides>
                    </ion-card>

                  <ion-card>
                    <ion-item>
                      <ion-avatar item-start>
                        <img src="../../assets/imgs/mwicigi.jpg">
                      </ion-avatar>
                      <h2>Moses Mwicigi</h2>
                      <p>May 10th 2018</p>

                    </ion-item>
                    <div>
                      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                        <img src="../../assets/imgs/mwicigi.jpg"></ion-thumbnail>
                      </div>

                      <ion-card-content>
                        <p>The Lord is my strength and shield. I trust him with all my heart. He helps me, and my heart is filled with joy. I burst out in songs of thanksgiving.</p>
                      </ion-card-content>

                      <ion-row>
                        <ion-col>
                          <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
                            <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
                            <div>12 Likes</div>
                          </button>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col>
                          <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
                            <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
                            <div>4 Comments</div>
                          </button>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col center text-center>
                          <ion-note>
                            11h ago
                          </ion-note>
                        </ion-col>
                      </ion-row>
                    </ion-card>

                      <ion-card >
                        <ion-item color="partial" text-center>
                          Watch our Video
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-slides>
                          <ion-slide>
                            <ion-row>
                              <ion-col col-6>
                                <div>
                                  <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                    <img (click)="gotovideopage()" style="width: 100%"  src="../../assets/imgs/love2.jpg" ></ion-thumbnail>
                                  </div>
                                  <p>Giving is an act of worship Part 1</p>
                                  <button ion-button block (click)="gotovideopage()"> Play Video</button>
                                </ion-col>

                                <ion-col col-6>
                                  <div>
                                    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                      <img (click)="playVideo()" style="width: 100%"  src="../../assets/imgs/love3.jpg" ></ion-thumbnail>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>Let build the Online Outreach Center</p>
                                    <button ion-button block (click)="gotovideopage()"> Play Video</button>
                                  </ion-col>
                                </ion-row>
                              </ion-slide>
                              <ion-slide>
                                <ion-row>
                                  <ion-col col-6>
                                    <div>
                                      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                        <img (click)="playVideo()" style="width: 100%"  src="../../assets/imgs/dating1.jpg" ></ion-thumbnail>
                                      </div>
                                      <p>Giving is an act of worship Part 1</p>
                                      <button ion-button (click)="playVideo()"> Play Video</button>
                                    </ion-col>

                                    <ion-col col-6>
                                      <div>
                                        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                          <img (click)="playVideo()" style="width: 100%"  src="../../assets/imgs/dating.jpg" ></ion-thumbnail>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Let build the Online Outreach Center</p>
                                        <button ion-button block (click)="playVideo()"> Play Video</button>
                                      </ion-col>
                                    </ion-row>
                                  </ion-slide>

                                  <ion-slide>
                                    <ion-row>
                                      <ion-col col-6>
                                        <div>
                                          <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                            <img (click)="playVideo()" style="width: 100%"  src="../../assets/imgs/dating3.jpg" ></ion-thumbnail>
                                          </div>
                                          <p>Giving is an act of worship Part 1</p>
                                          <button ion-button (click)="playVideo()"> Play Video</button>
                                        </ion-col>

                                        <ion-col col-6>
                                          <div>
                                            <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                              <img (click)="playVideo()" style="width: 100%"  src="../../assets/imgs/dating.jpg" ></ion-thumbnail>
                                            </div>
                                            <p>Let build the Online Outreach Center</p>
                                            <button ion-button block (click)="playVideo()"> Play Video</button>
                                          </ion-col>
                                        </ion-row>
                                      </ion-slide>
                                    </ion-slides>
                                  </ion-card>


                                  <ion-card>
                                    <ion-card-header text-center> Our Events</ion-card-header>
                                    <hr/>
                                    <ion-slides>
                                      <ion-slide col-6 *ngFor="let events of (eventsDataList | async)?.slice().reverse()" detail-push navPush="EventsPage" [root]="{events:events}">
                                          <ion-row>
                                            <ion-col class="textleft">
                                              <div>
                                                <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                                                  <img style="width: 100%"  src="../../assets/imgs/dating3.jpg"></ion-thumbnail>
                                                </div>
                                                <p>{{events.heading}}</p>
                                              </ion-col>
                                            </ion-row>
                                          </ion-slide>
                                        </ion-slides>
                                      </ion-card>
                                    </ion-content>
```

> home.module.ts

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

i have tried to insert ActivatedRoute and still nothing has changed, am new into the ionic-v4 coding.

> home.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController, NavParams, ToastController, Input } from '@ionic/angular';
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player/ngx';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Profile } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HomeProvider } from '../../service/church.service';
import { ProfilePage } from '../profile/profile';
import { DefaultPage } from '../default/default';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {VideosPage} from '../videos/videos';
import {Blog } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { MyBlogProvider } from '../../service/church.service';
import { SermonProvider } from '../../service/church.service';
import { Sermon } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Events } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { MyEventsProvider } from '../../service/church.service';
import { Announcements } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { MyAnnouncementsProvider } from '../../service/church.service';
import { Verse } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { MyVerseProvider } from '../../service/church.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  [x: string]: any;


  profileData: Observable<Profile[]>;
  eventsDataList: Observable<Events[]>;
  blogDataList: Observable<Blog[]>;
  verseDataList: Observable<Verse[]>;
  sermonData: Observable<Sermon[]>;
  announcementsDataList: Observable<Announcements[]>;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private afauth: AngularFireAuth,
              private toast: ToastController,
              private profile: HomeProvider,
              private sermon: SermonProvider,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private blogprovider: MyBlogProvider,
              private eventsprovider: MyEventsProvider,
              private verseprovider: MyVerseProvider,
              private announcementsprovider: MyAnnouncementsProvider,
              private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
              public modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private youtube: YoutubeVideoPlayer,
            public http: Http) {

          {
            this.profileData = this.profile
            .getProfile()
            .snapshotChanges()
            .map(
              changes => {
                return changes.map(c => ({
                  key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val(),
                }));
              }
            );

        }
          {
            this.blogDataList = this.blogprovider
            .getBlog()
            .snapshotChanges()
            .map(
              changes => {
                return changes.map(c => ({
                  key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val(),
                }));
              }
            );
          }
            {
                this.sermonData = this.sermon
                .getSermon()
                .snapshotChanges()
                .map(
                  changes => {
                    return changes.map(c => ({
                      key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val(),
                    }));
                  }
                );
            }

          {
            this.eventsDataList = this.eventsprovider
            .getEvents()
            .snapshotChanges()
            .map(
              changes => {
                return changes.map(c => ({
                  key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val(),
                }));
              }
            );
        }
            {
                this.announcementsDataList = this.announcementsprovider
                .getAnnouncements()
                .snapshotChanges()
                .map(
                  changes => {
                    return changes.map(c => ({
                      key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val(),
                    }));
                  }
                );
          }
          {
              this.verseDataList = this.verseprovider
              .getVerse()
              .snapshotChanges()
              .map(
                changes => {
                  return changes.map(c => ({
                    key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val(),
                  }));
                }
              );
        }

      }




  ionViewWillLoad() {

      this.afauth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if (data && data.email && data.uid) {

      this.toast.create({
        message: `Welcome to Church App, ${data.email}`,
        duration: 3000,
      }).catch();
    } else {
      this.toast.create({
        message: `could not find authentication details`,
        duration: 3000,
      }).catch();
    }

    });
  }

  editprofile() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('ProfilePage');
  }

  gotovideopage() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('VideosPage');
  }


}
```

Comment: `root` is not a input property of `ion-button` https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/button/Button/

Comment: how can i correct it?

Comment: why are u using root in the button

Comment: at first it was navparams and it wasnt connecting and i was trying to chnge to the ionic v4 beta

Comment: it should be in nav https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/Nav/

Comment: tried that and no change